# while statement which will include all indexes of the list

Tags: c#, while-loop

I have such while statement

```
while (selectedDish != listOfObjectDishes[0].Dish.ToString()
    || selectedDish != listOfObjectDishes[1].Dish.ToString()
    || selectedDish != listOfObjectDishes[2].Dish.ToString())
{}
```

the list has 13 indexes and I want to include them all (each index of the list) How Can I do it right?

Comment: Which language do you use? Most languages have some function to check if an array contains a specific value.

Comment: c# , sorry I forgot to mention

Comment: I have diffrent types (list is with type of my own class) so Im not able to use contains because I have exception that  it cant be converted from string to my own class. I thougth that there is so simplest way to include it in indexes . some kind of ranges instead of multiplaying "or"  in While loop

Comment: You can use the `.Any()` Linq method to query against all `.Dish` values: `while (listOfObjectDishes.Any(x => x.Dish.ToString() != selectedDish)){ }`

Comment: yep, its work - thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the easiest way would be to use the linq library's extension method [`any()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.any) to check your list.

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Collections.Generic;
                    
public class Program {
    public static void Main() {

        List<Dish> listOfObjectDishes = new List<Dish>();
        listOfObjectDishes.Add(new Dish("a"));
        listOfObjectDishes.Add(new Dish("b"));
        listOfObjectDishes.Add(new Dish("c"));
        
        while(listOfObjectDishes.Any(dish => dish.ToString() == "b")) {
            Console.WriteLine("Removing: " + listOfObjectDishes[0].ToString());
            listOfObjectDishes.RemoveAt(0);
        }
    }
}

public class Dish
{
    private string name =  string.Empty;
    public Dish(string name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    
    public override string ToString() {
        return name;    
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks :) using any()  I have achieved what I wanted

Comment: @Slide Glad I could help, please accept this answer (check mark on the left) so other people know you don't need further assistance.